# UIScrollview in UIactionsheet is not working

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiactionsheet, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a view (objViewComments) that contains scrollview and its working fine. but now i have added this view in UIActionsheet using below code :

```
myActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
        myActionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
        objViewComments.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
        objViewComments.myTempActionSheet = myActionSheet;
        //myActionSheet.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
        [myActionSheet showInView:self.navigationController.view];
        [myActionSheet addSubview:objViewComments.view];
        [myActionSheet release]
```

But now the scrollview is not working. and throws error :

```
[UIImageView scrollViewDidScroll:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x18f480'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, it is likely that your scrollview delegate is wrongly wired up.

Comment: I checked and its right wired up bcoz if i add view directly without Action sheet then it works fine... :)

Comment: Its just that a `UIImageView` object seems to be getting the delegate messages. So which object is acting as the scroll view's delegate?